# How to save a shared video to my Camera Roll on iOS?

Tags: ios, ipad, video, photos, camera-roll

I have the app Photos on my iPad mini, on iOS 7.

I am viewing a stream shared by a friend.

When I am on a photo, I can save it to my Camera Roll.

But, when I am on a video, I cannot save it to my Camera Roll. The feature is missing.

**1) How can I save a video to my Camera Roll ?**

I want preferably a solution that do not need a computer.

**2) *Bonus question :* Why has Apple limited this feature to photos ?**

Comment: This is also missing in iOS 8.1.2 on my iPhone.. Just tried, there is no obvious way to manipulate (save/share/etc) a shared vid.  Neither the "Edit" or forward buttons that opens the functionality for a pic is present on the screen.

Comment: Have you tried to do this via icloud.com and download it from there?

Comment: I cannot answer due to lack of reputation, but in addition to bmike's solution, there is another (imperfect) workaround, which is to open the icloud link on a desktop (e.g. macbook) and the video will automatically download. Then you can do whatever you want with it (e.g. airdrop to your iPhone's camera roll)

Answer (score 1):

Apple doesn't have a solution on iOS to accomplish this. I've not found any third party app from the App Store that will read the shared stream videos or receive a paste event (you can copy the video from Photos app on iOS, but pasting it anywhere seems to not work for me on iOS 8.x)

I use iPhoto on OS X to view the shared video and then import them into my library. From there, I can get the videos onto iOS. Not exactly your preferred solution, but it works well enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the video and paste it in an iMessage to yourself.

Comment: The peoblem with this solution is iMessage videos are limited in duration, AND down-sampled.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe have your friend email you the video or upload it to  Dropbox or MEGA as private. Those websites allow you to download the videos

**EDIT**
Those website allow you to download the videos NOT from the stock iOS Photos app but from the websites.

Comment: There are many, many ways for the friend to share the video in a way you can then use on iOS - but there's not a good way for an iOS app to pull it from the friend's stream directly.

Answer (score -2):

There are now apps that can download these online videos directly into your camera roll. Most are free for basic functions and the ones that I have used include Video Download.

Comment: Can you name one?